# Happy New Year! Suppose $H''(r)-aH'(r)=0$ and $H'(0)=\frac{1}{p^2}$. Find the "special solution" for $H'(0)=\frac{H'(0)}{a}\cdot(1+\frac{N}{Y}e^w)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recreational-mathematics

> Suppose that $H''(r)-aH'(r)=0$, $H'(0)=\frac{1}{p^2}$. Find the "special solution" for $$H(0)=\dfrac{H'(0)}{a}\cdot(1+\frac{N}{Y}e^w)$$

**Solution:**

Since
$$\lambda^2-a\lambda=0\text{ has roots }\lambda=0 \text{ and }\lambda=a $$
We have:
$$H(r)=C_0+C_1e^{ar},\text{ where $C_0,C_1$ =const.} \\H(0)=C_0+C_1,~~H'(0)=aC_1$$
We have:$$C_1=\frac{1}{ap^2},~ C_0=H(0)-C_1=\frac{1}{ap^2}\cdot\frac{N}{Y}e^w$$
Hence, $$H=\frac{1}{ap^2}\cdot\frac{N}{Y}e^w+\frac{1}{ap^2}e^{ar}$$

> We deduce that:$$Hap^2Y=Ne^w+Ye^{ar}$$
>   $$\bf{\text{Happy New Year!!!}}$$